# How to multi line string in terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying below from an example

```
resource "google_logging_metric" "my_metric" { 
  description = "Check for logs of some cron job\t" 
  name        = "mycj-logs" 
  filter      = "resource.type=\"k8s_container\" AND resource.labels.cluster_name=\"${local.k8s_name}\" AND resource.labels.namespace_name=\"workable\" AND resource.labels.container_name=\"mycontainer-cronjob\" \nresource.labels.pod_name:\"my-pod\"" 
  project     = "${data.terraform_remote_state.gke_k8s_env.project_id}" 
 
  metric_descriptor { 
    metric_kind = "DELTA" 
    value_type  = "INT64" 
  } 
}
```

Is there a way to make the filter field multiline?

Answer (score 10):

If it's a matter of formatting the output, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69257431/2480947) covers it.

If you want to make your code more readable, i.e. split the long string into multiple clauses with a common separator, I've found `join()` useful:

```
resource "google_logging_metric" "my_metric" { 
  description = "Check for logs of some cron job\t" 
  name        = "mycj-logs" 
  project     = "${data.terraform_remote_state.gke_k8s_env.project_id}" 
  filter = join(" AND ",
    [
        "resource.type=\"k8s_container\"",
        "resource.labels.cluster_name=\"${local.k8s_name}\"",
        "resource.labels.namespace_name=\"workable\"",
        "resource.labels.container_name=\"mycontainer-cronjob\"",
        "resource.labels.pod_name:\"my-pod\""
    ]
  ) 
  metric_descriptor { 
    metric_kind = "DELTA" 
    value_type  = "INT64" 
  } 
}
```

Note that setting out the code this way shows that in the OP there may (or may not) be a missing AND in the `filter` expression, between the last and second last clauses.

Because the original expression is one long line, this is very hard to see and slow to read/maintain. With the join expression the intent is clearer I think.

Answer (score 6):

A quick search in Google sends you to the documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#heredoc-strings

You just need to write something like

```
<<EOT
hello
world
EOT
```